# Empty space between two shapes in GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+

I am trying to draw a custom drop shadow in GDI+ (C#). I keep having this awkward look:
[image: Preview]

I guess I could solve it by adding a pixel to the arc's width, but then the shapes overlap.
[Preview http://puu.sh/2sv2N](http://puu.sh/2sv2N)

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this small piece of white.

Here's my code:

```cs
Rectangle drawRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 400, 400);
radius = 10;
// TOP //
Rectangle topRect = new Rectangle(drawRect.X + radius, drawRect.Y, drawRect.Width - 2 * radius, radius);
LinearGradientBrush topBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(topRect.X, topRect.Y - 1, topRect.Width,topRect.Height + 2), firstColor, secondColor, 270f);
g.FillRectangle(topBrush, topRect);
topBrush.Dispose();

// LEFT //
Rectangle leftRect = new Rectangle(drawRect.X, drawRect.Y + radius, radius, drawRect.Height - 2 * radius);
LinearGradientBrush leftBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(leftRect.X - 1, leftRect.Y, leftRect.Width + 2, leftRect.Height), firstColor, secondColor, 180f);
g.FillRectangle(leftBrush, leftRect);
leftBrush.Dispose();

// TOP LEFT //
GraphicsPath topLeftPath = new GraphicsPath();
topLeftPath.StartFigure();
topLeftPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(drawRect.X, drawRect.Y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius), 180, 90);
topLeftPath.AddLine(new Point(drawRect.X + radius, drawRect.Y), new Point(drawRect.X + radius, drawRect.Y + radius));
topLeftPath.AddLine(new Point(drawRect.X + radius, drawRect.Y + radius), new Point(drawRect.X, drawRect.Y + radius + 1));
topLeftPath.CloseFigure();
PathGradientBrush topLeftBrush = new PathGradientBrush(topLeftPath);
topLeftBrush.CenterPoint = new PointF(drawRect.X + radius, drawRect.Y + radius);
topLeftBrush.CenterColor = firstColor;
topLeftBrush.SurroundColors = new Color[] { secondColor };
g.FillPath(topLeftBrush, topLeftPath);
topLeftBrush.Dispose();
topLeftPath.Dispose();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: off-topic comment: did you know the same effect can be achieved with 2 lines of XAML in XAML-based technologies (such as WPF or WinRT)? I guess I have to say that GDI doesn't support "nice" things.

Comment: Yeah I know I should have quit GDI+ & just use WPF, but I can't just redo my whole solution.

Comment: Still, you can integrate WPF content into an existing winforms application via the `ElementHost`. It's much easier to do things in WPF and then integrate them that way than trying to hack thru winforms to get something decent out of it.

Comment: Haven't got any experience in WPf though, I'd still like to know why this problem is occurring.

Comment: Try `e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to LarsTech, I got the working solution.

```
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```

That did the job.

Thank you !

Comment: Ask Lars to post this as an answer and then accept his answer. This would reward his contribution.